# React JS Custom Component Animation

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, animation

I have a ReactJS component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class Circle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            percent: null
        };
    }    

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = "base url here" + this.props.endpoint;
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        percent: result.percent
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error: error
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"col-md-" + this.props.size + " progress-circles"} data-animate-on-scroll="on">
                <div className="progress-circle" data-circle-percent={"" + this.state.percent + ""} data-circle-text="">
                <h4>{this.props.title}</h4>
                    <svg className="progress-svg">
                        <circle r="80" cx="90" cy="90" fill="transparent" strokeDasharray="502.4" strokeDashoffset="0"></circle>
                        <circle className="bar" r="80" cx="90" cy="90" fill="transparent" strokeDasharray="502.4" strokeDashoffset="0"></circle>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Circle;
```

So far, this works like a total charm. The only problem is that there's an animation associated with this element that fills in the progress-circle and it doesn't occur after I've set the value from the `componentDidMount` function. The animation **does** occur if I set the value via props from the parent component. Am I missing something? I'm new to React so it could be something simple. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your solution is you are rendering animation always irrespective of whether you do fetch call or not.

Few things I would like to explain here before solution

> 1. Make isLoaded to true before fetch call in componentDidMount
> 2. When you get success/error response turn isLoaded to false
> 3. When you get success response you should also change your error state to null to make it work second time
> 4. When you get error response you should also change your percent state to null to make it work second time
> 5. Show loader when isLoaded is true, error and percent both null
> 6. Show success response when percent is not null, isLoaded false and error is null
> 7. Show error response when error is not null, isLoaded false and percent is null

This is how I normally do in my application

```
import React from 'react';

class Circle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            percent: null
        };
    }    

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = "base url here" + this.props.endpoint;
        this.setState({
            isLoaded: true
        });
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: false,
                        percent: result.percent,
                        error: null
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: false,
                        error: error,
                        percent: null
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoaded } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className={"col-md-" + this.props.size + " progress-circles"} data-animate-on-scroll="on">
                {isLoaded && percent == null && error == null && (<div className="progress-circle" data-circle-percent={"" + this.state.percent + ""} data-circle-text="">
                <h4>{this.props.title}</h4>
                    <svg className="progress-svg">
                        <circle r="80" cx="90" cy="90" fill="transparent" strokeDasharray="502.4" strokeDashoffset="0"></circle>
                        <circle className="bar" r="80" cx="90" cy="90" fill="transparent" strokeDasharray="502.4" strokeDashoffset="0"></circle>
                    </svg>
                </div>)}
                {!isLoaded && percent != null && <h2>Success response</h2>}
                {!isLoaded && error != null && <h2>error occured</h2>}
            </div>
        );
    }}

    export default Circle;
```

Hope this answers your query

Comment: Hi! This helped a lot but I think I discovered the root of the problem - the animation is triggered by a function that is called in a `scripts.js` file on load. So I think it's just missing the element that's there since it loads after the script is run. Is there a way to re-trigger an arbitrary javascript function again? I currently have it imported to the page via `index.html` and the file is in my `Public` folder.

Comment: Share your index.html file